# Node.js is app is not listening on specified port

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I am specify port 30000, but the app ends up listening on a different port.

This is the code I am using:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(30000, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port %d', app.listen().address().port);
});
```

The port the app is listening to gets set to a different value when it runs. If I use the value that it logs to the console in the browser, it works properly.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `app.listen()` twice - the second time in the argument to `console.log`.

The second one has no port as argument so it chooses a random port.

Change this:

```
app.listen(30000, function() {
    console.log('Server started on port %d', app.listen().address().port);
});
```

to:

```
var listener = app.listen(30000, function () {
   console.log('Server started on port %d', listener.address().port);
});
```